# Why can't one switch back to the default mode on Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, magento-2.0.4, command-line, developer-mode

So I have switched to the developer mode while developing on a Magento 2 project using the following command:

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

All good, I got this message and I developed the website fine:

> Current application mode: developer.

For some reasons, I wanted to go back to the `default` mode just to check the behavior of the website in this mode. No specific reasons to be honest, I just wanted to switch back to this mode.

So I ran the following command:

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set default
```

But I got this weird error with no further explanations:

```
Cannot switch into given mode "default"
```

I checked the following file that handles the mode settings `Magento/Deploy/Console/Command/SetModeCommand.php` and here's what I've found:

```
switch($toMode) {
    case State::MODE_DEVELOPER:
        $modeController->enableDeveloperMode();
        break;
    case State::MODE_PRODUCTION:
        if ($skipCompilation) {
            $modeController->enableProductionModeMinimal();
        } else {
            $modeController->enableProductionMode();
        }
        break;
    default:
        throw new LocalizedException(__('Cannot switch into given mode "%1"', $toMode));
}
```

How weird is that, **Magento 2 is shipped in default mode but you can't switch back to that specific mode**. What's the reason behind this ?

Edit: for those interested I ended up creating an issue on github: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4292

Comment: It is very good question, and we were gathering feedback why would you want to use default mode, but not developer. And seems like you define the reason as "No specific reasons".
But I agree - we must allow to on/off the mode, since it is by default. At the moment we have in our backlog task to add it in list possible modes.

Comment: One reason would be:  I have developed an extension and some of my customers might be running in default mode

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The default mode is neither here nor there.

[image: mode overview]

The Magento team really wants you to use either Production Mode on your live site or Developer Mode during Development. The reason why Default Mode exists is to have something that would at least run reasonably when deployed directly from the downloaded code without further intervention.

By running `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set` you have identified yourself as capable and not needing the default mode. As there is no reason needing to go back to default mode Magento did not provide a way for you to do so.

Comment: I knew I should have taken that picture. By the way you were sitting 5-6 chairs on my left :)

Comment: @Marius haha maybe the reason why you're 1 vote behind in the upvoted answers ^^

Comment: Ended up creating an issue: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4292

Comment: The reason you are one vote ahead is because I upvoted you :).

Comment: The reason Marius is behind is I downvoted him :-P

Comment: #thingsILearnedAtImagine :)

Comment: The reason wanting to switch back to "Default" mode is clearly because "developer" mode is too slow. Testing your page is an important part of development and should not be slowed down nor have the need to fully deploy everything using "production" mode. As a developer I chose rather to suffer the downsides of "default" mode than being forced to decide between "developer" and "production"

Answer (score 19):

The default mode is there only to install Magento 2.
It should not be used for development or production.
After installation you can only switch between dev and prod.

Source: Alan Kent @MagentoImagine2016

Comment: Ended up creating an issue: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4292

Answer (score 11):

As a windows developer, in developer mode, Magento wants to create symbolic links to the static assets, but uses the Linux command and not the windows command. This creates a lot of errors in the js and css files.

To switch back to default mode, open:-

```
app/etc/env.php
```

And change:-

```
'MAGE_MODE' => 'developer',
```

Back to:-

```
'MAGE_MODE' => 'default',
```

And re-deploy static files again.

Comment: Note: Environment variables may override this value.

Comment: Note that Magento doesn't officially support Windows, so trying to develop on Windows could produce other problems as well.

Answer (score 1):

I ran with the same problem, but changing it in `env.php` manually works.

Comment: Yeah of course I know I could it directly I was just wondering why it's not possible via the CLI

Answer (score 1):

[image: **set mode 2.3.x**]

Now Magento allowing us to switch back to default mode from 2.3.x