# About error while enabling developer mode

Tags: magento2.2, developer-mode

Magento 2.2
When I enable developer mode, the Magento doesnot work and displays this error instead

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Theme layout update file ' public_html/app/design/frontend/Mgs/XXX/Magento_Contact/layout/contact_index_index.xml' is not valid.
XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document
 Line: 2

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Theme layout update file ' public_html/app/design/frontend/Mgs/XXX/Magento_Contact/layout/contact_index_index.xml' is not valid.
XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document
 Line: 2
#0  public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php(662): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->_loadFileLayoutUpdatesXml()
#1  public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge/Interceptor.php(245): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->getFileLayoutUpdatesXml()
#2  public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php(535): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge\Interceptor->getFileLayoutUpdatesXml()
#3  public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php(514): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->_fetchPackageLayoutUpdates('default')
#4  public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php(438): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->_merge('default')
#5  public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->load(Array)
#6  public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(86): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge\Interceptor->load()
#7  public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(63): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->loadLayoutUpdates()
#8  public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(254): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
#9  public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(875): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build()
#10  public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(414): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock('page_content_he...')
#11  public_html/vendor/magento/module-cms/Helper/Page.php(171): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getBlock('page_content_he...')
#12  public_html/vendor/magento/module-cms/Controller/Index/Index.php(43): Magento\Cms\Helper\Page->prepareResultPage(Object(Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), 'home')
#13  public_html/generated/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index->execute(NULL)
#14  public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(107): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->execute()
#15  public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#16  public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#17  public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#18  public_html/generated/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#19  public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#20  public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#21  public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#22  public_html/vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#23  public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24  public_html/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#25  public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#26  public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27  public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)
#28  public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#29  public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#30  public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#31 {main}
```

contact_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
        <action method="setPageTitle">
            <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Contact</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</page>
```

Cannot switch into given mode "default"

```
The directory "public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework" cannot be deleted Warning!rmdir(public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework): Directory not empty
```

Comment: Open  contact_index_index.xml and post it here, it looks like it is importly formatted from the error. file is located at app/design/frontend/Mgs/unero/Magento_Contact/layout/contact_index_index.xml. You'll probably find that the XML definition was put on the second line of the file, instead of the first. Or it has been defined twice

Comment: @Eirik update
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
 <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
  <action method="setPageTitle">
   <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Contact</argument>
  </action>
 </referenceBlock>
</page>

Comment: Update your original post with the contents, we cant read it in its original format when added as a comment.

Comment: @Eirik updated ^^"

Comment: Is there an extra line or spacing before <?xml version="1.0"?>  ? It will throw the error you are seeing if there is anything before the opening xml declaration

Comment: @Eirik yes spacing before

Comment: remove the spacing and save the file then reupload it. should correct the problem

Comment: can i ask you something, if my path is /opt/alt/php71/usr/bin/php /home/abc/public_html/ . add chmod -R u+w . in where? how to make files and directories writable, for update components and upgrade the Magento software. thank you! @Eirik

Comment: Magentos developer documentation has a large write up on that http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html

Comment: @Eirik i getting some issue , Cannot switch into given mode "default" ... i update in original  post

Answer (score 1):

@rigu Once you change modes from "Default" to either "Developer" or "Production" modes - you **CAN NOT** revert back to "Default" mode.

[image: Red Pill vs Blue Pill]

This StackExchange thread has more information on the topic - [Why can't one switch back to the default mode on Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112523/why-cant-one-switch-back-to-the-default-mode-on-magento-2)

There is an open M2x ticket requesting that "feature" be added -
 but, FWIW, I wouldn't hold my breath -
 https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4292

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `referenceBlock` tag inside the `body` tag. Maybe it will help!