# Set Default to developer mode issue

Tags: magento2, static-content-deploy

When We set mode default to a developer, files are removed from pub folder.

[image]

Magento 2.x
PHP 7.x

Comment: can you check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112523/why-cant-one-switch-back-to-the-default-mode-on-magento-2

Answer (score 1):

Try to clear the content of bellow folders except `.htaccess`:

```
var/cache
var/di
var/generation
var/view_preprocessed
pub/static
```

Then launch your command: `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`

Comment: Can you tell me how to delete media, opt and static folder from pub folder when I run the php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer?

Comment: To clean static files cache:  `rm -R pub/static/*`